# Gradient across nav, not li

Tags: html, css

for some reason, I'm having trouble applying a gradient horizontally across the nav bar. It makes the element disappear, but it is ok when I apply it to the li. What's going on? You can take a look at the site at http://jcdevelopmentsite.com/spaoftheearth/index-spa.html

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en-us'>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'/>
        <title>Homepage | Spa of the Earth</title>
        <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='images/favicon.png'/>
        <meta name='keywords' content='Spa of the earth, spa, massage, facial, treatment, mud, organic, natural'>
        <meta name='description' content='Luscious spa services including facials, body wraps, etc'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles-home.css'>

        <script src='jquery-awesomeness.js'></script>

        <!-- Slider Link -->
        <script src='responsiveslides.min.js'></script>

        <!-- Social Media Plugins from sharethis.com -->
        <script type='text/javascript'>var switchTo5x=true;</script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://s.sharethis.com/loader.js'></script>

        <script>
            // Slider Functions
            $(function() {
                $('.rslides').responsiveSlides({
                    speed: 750,
                    timeout: 3000
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- header -->
        <header id='home'>
            <img id='header-logo' src='images/header-logo.jpg' alt='Logo: Spa of the Earth'>
        </header>

        <!-- nav -->
        <nav role='navigation'>
            <ul id='menu'>
                <li><a href='index-spa.html'>Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#specials'>Specials</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='appointments.html'>Appointments</a>
                    <ul class='submenu'>
                        <li><a href='#facials'>Facials</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#body'>Body</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#oncology'>Oncology</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#ayurveda'>Ayurveda</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#energy'>Energy Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#divination'>Divination</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='events.html'>Events</a>
                    <ul class='submenu'>
                        <li><a href='#reiki'>Reiki</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#evens'>Special Events</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='about.html'>About Us</a>
                    <ul class='submenu'>
                        <li>
                            <a href='http://jcdevelopmentsite.com/spaoftheearth/about.html#wiesje'>Wiesje Brion</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#media'>Media</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#testimonials'>Testimonials</a></li>
                        <li><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='help.html'>Help</a>
                    <ul class='submenu'>
                        <li><a href='#policies'>Policies</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#privacy'>Privacy Notice</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#faq'>FAQ</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='blog.html'>Blog</a>
                    <ul class='submenu'>
                        <li><a href='#homebeauty'>Home Beauty</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#astrology'>Astrology</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- #welcome -->               
        <section id='welcome'>
            <div id='slider'>
                <ul class='rslides'>
                    <li><img src='images/slide1.jpg'></li>
                    <li><img src='images/slide2.jpg'></li>
                    <li><img src='images/slide3.jpg'></li>
                    <li><img src='images/slide4.jpg'></li>
                </ul>
                <img id='frame' src='images/sliderframe.png'>
            </div>

            <div class='content'>
                <h2>Treat Yourself to a Natural, Soul Pleasing Experience!</h2>
                <p>At Spa of the Earth, we specialize in naturopathic healing inspired by ancient Ayurvedic principles. We tailor our holistic treatments to your dosha type, targeting your spirit amd individuality. Restore, rejuvenate and balance with the best wild-crafted botanical treatments available, hand-made by Spa of the Earth. 
                </p>
                <br>
                <p>Schedule an appointment today for an extraordinary experience in beauty, skin care and wellness.
                </p>
            </div> <!-- Closes #content -->
        </section>



        <!-- Social Media Plugin from sharethis.com -->
        <script type='text/javascript'>stLight.options({publisher: '69520918-4da3-4dbc-aa1c-ceb74de78ee9', doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});
        </script>
        <script>
            var options={ 'publisher': '69520918-4da3-4dbc-aa1c-ceb74de78ee9', 'position': 'right', 'ad': { 'visible': false, 'openDelay': 5, 'closeDelay': 0}, 'chicklets': { 'items': ['facebook', 'twitter']}};
            var st_hover_widget = new sharethis.widgets.hoverbuttons(options);
        </script>
        <!-- Closes Social Media Plugin -->
        <!-- jQuery for Dropdown Menu -->
        <script>
        var timer;

            $('.parent').on('mouseover', function() {
              clearTimeout(timer);
              openSubmenu();
            }).on('mouseleave', function() {
              timer = setTimeout(
                closeSubmenu
              , 1000);
            });

            function openSubmenu() {
              $('.submenu').addClass('open');
            }
            function closeSubmenu() {
              $('.submenu').removeClass('open');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* =========================        Primary CSS Styles for Spa of the Earth        ========================= */



/* ==============================                   Basic Reset                   ============================== */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'champagne__limousinesregular';
    color: #7A7A7A;
    }



/* ==============================                Begin CSS Styles                 ============================== */

/* ==============================                  Web Font Kits                  ============================== */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bebasregular';
    src: url('fonts/bebas/bebas___-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/bebas/bebas___-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/bebas/bebas___-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/bebas/bebas___-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }

@font-face {
    font-family: 'champagne__limousinesregular';
    src: url('fonts/champagne/champagne__limousines-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/champagne/champagne__limousines-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/champagne/champagne__limousines-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/champagne/champagne__limousines-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/champagne/champagne__limousines-webfont.svg#champagne__limousinesregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }



@font-face {
    font-family: 'chopinscriptmedium';
    src: url('fonts/chopin/chopinscript-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/chopin/chopinscript-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/chopin/chopinscript-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/chopin/chopinscript-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/chopin/chopinscript-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/chopin/chopinscript-webfont.svg#chopinscriptmedium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }



/* ==============================                Structural Styles                ============================== */
header {
    width: 100%;
    }



/* ==============================                    Nav Styles                   ============================== */
nav {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'champagne__limousinesregular';
    }

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    }

nav li {
    width: 14.666%;
    padding: 1%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #aa893c, #806720, #e9d07c, #806720); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to left, #aa893c, #806720, #e9d07c, #806720); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to left, #aa893c, #806720, #e9d07c, #806720); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #aa893c, #806720, #e9d07c, #806720); /* Standard syntax */
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

nav li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    }

nav li:hover {
    @include transition(background, 0.2s);
    cursor: pointer;
    }

nav ul li ul {
    width: 95%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
    min-width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: visibility 0.65s ease-in;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    }

nav ul li:hover > ul, nav ul li ul:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    }

nav ul li ul li {
    clear: both;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
    width: 100%;
    }

nav ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #aaaaaa;
    }



/* ==============================               Submenu Styles              ============================== */



/* ==============================                   Main Content                  ============================== */
.content {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0 5%;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 2em;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    }



/* ==============================                Typographic Styles               ============================== */
h2 {
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    font-size: 'chopinscriptmedium';
    font-size: 1.75em;
    text-align: right;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    color: #009b9c;
    }

p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    }
```

Comment: The reason the gradient doesn't show when you put it on the `<nav>` us because it doesn't have any height / width first, try putting `display:inline-block;` on your `<nav>` and try to work form there

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- navbar  `display: inline-block;`
- navbar  `width: 100%;`
- and add gradient to sub menu items(nav>li>ul) and remove from menu
  items(nav>li)

---

```
nav {
    display: inline-block;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #aa893c, #806720, #e9d07c, #806720); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(to left, #aa893c, #806720, #e9d07c, #806720); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(to left, #aa893c, #806720, #e9d07c, #806720); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
        background: linear-gradient(to left, #aa893c, #806720, #e9d07c, #806720); /* Standard syntax */
    font-family: 'champagne__limousinesregular';
    }

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    }

nav li {
    width: 14.666%;
    padding: 1%;

    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

nav li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    }

nav li:hover {
    @include transition(background, 0.2s);
    cursor: pointer;
    }

nav ul li ul {
    width: 95%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
    min-width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: visibility 0.65s ease-in;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #aa893c, #806720, #e9d07c, #806720); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(to left, #aa893c, #806720, #e9d07c, #806720); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(to left, #aa893c, #806720, #e9d07c, #806720); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
        background: linear-gradient(to left, #aa893c, #806720, #e9d07c, #806720); /* Standard syntax */
    }

nav ul li:hover > ul, nav ul li ul:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    }

nav ul li ul li {
    clear: both;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
    width: 100%;
    }

nav ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #aaaaaa;
    }



/* ==============================               Submenu Styles              ============================== */
```